# Uploading file ie vs firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I'm working on a project and I have to make the same website on ie and firefox. I got a problem with the element `<input type="file"/>`
In fact, with i.e i got this :[image]

and with firefox this :

[image]

My problem is that with firefox there is no way to change remove the file after selecting one.

Can someone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe try a 'reset' type button?

Comment: Indeed, http://jsfiddle.net/4kmz3ngs/

Comment: I can't, because it will be not the behavior than i.e. I want, if it's possible the file directory too.

Comment: I just need to ge the same thing with mozilla and i.e., I can't add a button because my client doesn't want it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.

```
$clearButton.on('click', function(){
    $fileInput.val('');
});
```